# Problem creating a group in a repo : " yum-groups-manager: error: no such option: --default "

Tags: yum, repository

When you run:

```
 yum groupinfo "Desktop"
```

you get 3 categories..

- Mandatory Packages
- Default Packages
- Optional Packages

This is the command I ran:

```
yum-groups-manager -n "Desktop" --id=desktop --save=Desktop.xml \
--mandatory  \
NetworkManager \
NetworkManager-gnome  \
alsa-plugins-pulseaudio  \
at-spi  \
control-center  \
dbus  \
gdm  \
gdm-user-switch-applet  \
gnome-panel  \
gnome-power-manager  \
gnome-screensaver  \
gnome-session  \
gnome-terminal  \
gvfs-archive  \
gvfs-fuse  \
gvfs-smb \
metacity \
nautilus  \
notification-daemon  \
polkit-gnome  \
xdg-user-dirs-gtk  \
yelp \
--default  \
control-center-extra  \
eog  \
gdm-plugin-fingerprint  \
gnome-applets  \
gnome-media  \
gnome-packagekit  \
gnome-vfs2-smb  \
gok  \
openssh-askpass  \
orca  \
pulseaudio-module-gconf  \
pulseaudio-module-x11  \
rhn-setup-gnome  \
vino
```

This is the error message:

```
yum-groups-manager: error: no such option: --default
```

Why would this option not be available? Because if we are to run:

```
 yum groupinfo "Desktop"
```

Here is the result:

```
Group: Desktop
 Description: A minimal desktop that can also be used as a thin client.
 Mandatory Packages:
   NetworkManager
   NetworkManager-gnome
   alsa-plugins-pulseaudio
   at-spi
   control-center
   dbus
   gdm
   gdm-user-switch-applet
   gnome-panel
   gnome-power-manager
   gnome-screensaver
   gnome-session
   gnome-terminal
   gvfs-archive
   gvfs-fuse
   gvfs-smb
   metacity
   nautilus
   notification-daemon
   polkit-gnome
   xdg-user-dirs-gtk
   yelp
 Default Packages:
   control-center-extra
   eog
   gdm-plugin-fingerprint
   gnome-applets
   gnome-media
   gnome-packagekit
   gnome-vfs2-smb
   gok
   openssh-askpass
   orca
   pulseaudio-module-gconf
   pulseaudio-module-x11
   rhn-setup-gnome
   vino
 Optional Packages:
   sabayon-apply
   tigervnc-server
   xguest
```

As it can be seen, there is more than just the category called "mandatory". There is also "default" and "optional", and yet the attempt replicate this group fails above because it won't allow "default" category to be placed into the group that is being created.

#### UPDATE

I'm using CentOS Linux 6.4 desktop

Comment: What version + distro is this on?

Comment: @slm, centos linux 6.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've confirmed in several versions of Fedora as well as CentOS 6.x and that option definitely doesn't exist. I even looked in the [source tree](https://github.com/pnasrat/yum-utils) for `yum-utils` which is the package that `yum-config-manager` is a part of. This option, though logical, doesn't exist.

I did notice this option:

```
--grouppkgs=GROUPPKGS
                   filter which packages (all,optional etc) are shown
                   from groups
```

However this option doesn't show up in CentOS 6.x, seems to be too new, perhaps it's included in Fedora. This option sounds like what you're looking for.

#### Another way?

I did figure out that you can use `repoquery` to at least find out the packages that are part of the type (mandatory, default, etc.) within a Yum group.

#### Example

*optional*

```
$ repoquery -qg "Desktop" -l --grouppkgs=optional
sabayon-apply
xguest
tigervnc-server
```

*default*

```
$ repoquery -qg "basic-desktop" -l --grouppkgs=default
rhn-setup-gnome
control-center-extra
eog
gnome-packagekit
gok
gnome-media
gnome-vfs2-smb
openssh-askpass
pulseaudio-module-x11
pulseaudio-module-gconf
gnome-applets
orca
vino
gdm-plugin-fingerprint
```

I'm not sure if this fact helps you or not, there is no `--save` option for `repoquery` so you're likely going to have to construct some combination of the 2 tools would be my guess. I didn't quite follow what you're end game was here.